# Machine learning model to predict column names based on column data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, prediction

I'm trying to build a Python machine learning model that can predict column names of unseen column data, based on previous datasets. For a simplified example a training dataframe can look like:

| Currency | Security Number |
| --- | --- |
| USD | 000402625 |
| CAD | 001477825 |
| USD | 200398025 |
| USD | 000403458 |
| JPY | 099402464 |
| EUR | 458592625 |

where the model would find a way to distinguish currencies from security numbers, and then feeding this test dataframe to the model:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| CAD | 500235025 |
| CAD | 200394855 |
| EUR | 999398025 |
| EUR | 234890578 |
| USD | 980758345 |
| JPY | 123754890 |

would identify column **X** = Currency and column **Y** = Security Number

I've did research and couldn't find anything that would allow predictions based on full column data, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to provide some more context on what kind of columns you have, because as it stands you can just look at the data types.

Comment: @mcsoini Let's say I have another column "Name" that also contains strings, but those strings would be of different pattern than currency, that I want a ML model to pick up on

Comment: I think you are better of with some heuristics (known strings like currency names, some regex matches if necessary, etc.) to piece it together. For example, there'll be only a very limited possible set of currency strings; if a columns contains largely those (allowing for some hickups), it's certainly currencies. "Security number" should be able to be cast to int, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the possible currencies are known you can get 100% accuracy by simply checking from a known list instead of making a prediction with a model.

But generally speaking, you can put all your data into one huge excel sheet, each row has a value and label. Then you shuffle your rows to make it random, and then you can train the whole thing.

| Value | Label |
| --- | --- |
| USD | Currency |
| 001477825 | Security Number |
| 000403458 | Security Number |
| EUR | Currency |

If you add enough data you should be able to predict that "BLA" is a currency and that 349834989 is a security number. Both are not correct but should be close enough to what you need :) This is what happens if you use machine learning :)

BUT

You will run into problems if you have several columns that all have numbers. **In that case, the numbers need to have a pattern that can be associated with that column**. That might simply not be the case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I do have other columns each with a unique pattern associated with that column, and what you're describing is exactly the type of ML model I need. How would you go by implementing this in Python though?

Comment: You should search for a basic tensorflow classification tutorial, that creates just a simple neural network for classification and loads an excel sheet. It's a bit of a hassle to google the right one, since many of those tutorials are about images for some reason.